# Wordpress Search query - exact post title match

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a bunch of posts titled something like this...

- English Language 2015
- English Language 2016
- English Language 2017
- English Language 2018

And on each one of these posts I have a dropdown select menu displaying posts with the same title, but different year. Here is my code for this. I am using Relavanssi plugin by the way:

```
<?php global $post;

$the_title = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', ' ', $post->post_title);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    's'         => $the_title,
    'sentence'  => true,            
    'exact'     => true,    
    'orderby'   => 'title',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'showposts' => -1
);  

$query = new WP_query($args);

relevanssi_do_query($query); 

    if ($query->post_count > 1) { ?>

        <h4>Years</h4>

        <select onchange="location = this.value;">

            <option disabled selected value>Select Year</option>

            <?php

            foreach ($query->posts as $r_post) {

                if ($r_post->ID == $post->ID ) continue;
                $link = get_permalink($r_post->ID);
                $title = get_the_title($r_post->ID);

                echo "<option value='$link'>$title</option>";

            }

            ?>

        </select>

 <?php } ?>
```

As you can see, I'm looking for the current post title and removing the years.

All good, HOWEVER, if I have more posts called something like...

- English Language and Literature 2015
- English Language and Literature 2016
- English Language and Literature 2017
- English Language and Literature 2018

...these posts will also display in the dropdown menu in the above 'English Language' posts, as it's picking up the phrase 'English Language', but I want an **exact** search query so it only displays 'English Language' posts on the dropdown of these posts.

I tried wrapping the $the_title var in quotes in attempt to do a phrase search but this did nothing.

Comment: try this :-------  's' => "[[:<:]]$the_title[[:>:]]"

Comment: check this link :-------------  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111018/how-to-tune-search-argument-in-wp-query-to-show-only-exactly-the-same-results

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion doesn't seem to work. The link is helpful but not quite relevant to this problem I'm afraid as that is dealing with no spaces in the query.

Comment: Using 's' will never be an exact match as it is WP-Query search argument. You could just look for just the post that is your exact match in the loop. Just do an if statement that says `if ($r_post === preg_match('/\b$the_title\b/', "YOURSEARCHSTRING"))`